# Updating to Salesforce user object using informatica

Tags: salesforce, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have three fields badge number, termination date and status to update to Salesforce based on badge number.im using update strategy in mapping and on session level -upsert with external lookup field as badge_number_c and treat source rows as data driven(session properties). However we get only 50 records updated and 20000 records rejected as badge numbers not present in target and those 20 k records trying to insert and hence rejected(since we did not map all fields to form record in Salesforce as we only update).. for this error log it consuming lot of time and wf run time is high.
I tried to remove upsert and external lookup field but it throws error as I'd field missing.. [image]

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are trying to update salesforce target using infa target definition and mixing two things.
If you are using only update strategy + treat source rows as data driven(session properties), then please ensure you handle update condition in update strategy.
For example,
First calculate `INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG` using some lookup on target by joining on primary key columns.
And then use it like below logic in update strategy.

```
IIF ( INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG = 'UPD',DD_UPDATE, DD_INSERT) -- if you want UPSERT logic.
or
IIF ( INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG = 'UPD',DD_UPDATE, IIF(1=2,DD_INSERT)) -- if you want only UPDATE logic.
```

Also pls note, you need to mention primary key columns in infa target definition otherwise update wont work.

Now as per your screenshot, if you want to use SFDC specific logic, probably, you need to be careful and follow below link to do this. Its a multi step process to create external id first and then use it to do lookup and update.
https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/124909?language=en_US

Comment: Seems like we can use joiner in mapping and join based on badge number and only get those badge numbers to downstream transformation.- update strategy (dd_update)and use upsert and external look up field badgenumber.. so only records present on target will be updated..

Comment: And does removing external look up field and upsert in sesion properties and using just update strategy(dd_update) update target based on badge number if it is defined as primary key in Salesforce?

Comment: yes, if you define badge num as PK in infa target definition, it should be good enough for update.